# scandir across domains on one vps

Tags: vps, permission-denied, scandir

can i use the php scandir command to grab photos from one domian and display them on another?

both are hosted on the same vps.

I have tried this:

```
$dir = '/home/user/public_html/assetts/media/users/'.$idContainer.'/photos/';
```

and i have tried this:

```
$dir = 'https://mymainwebsite.com/assetts/media/users/'.$idContainer.'/photos/';
```

Both of them return this error:

```
[function.scandir]: failed to open dir: Operation not permitted in
```

and this:

```
Warning: scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 13): Permission denied in
```

Im guessing it may be somewhow workable by setting up my users in WHM? or not?

Cheers in advance :)
Jonny

Comment: i figured my question might be stupid and very novice. Anyway i figured that i should write the photo names to the mysql database and call the file names from there. Then just use a loop query to display in img src tag rather than trying to read from directory using the scandir across domains.

Answer (score 0):

open_basedir restriction?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

or you have disabled the scandir function.
you also can use The DirectoryIterator class 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php